# Synchronize access between TFS and Sharepoint portal

Tags: sharepoint, tfs

in my setup each project in tfs 2015 has own project portal. But group permissions are different in tfs and sharepoint. Is there some approaches to synchronize them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn`t standard tools to synchronize users and permissions between TFS and SharePoint. I think you may try to use next ways:

1. Common active directory groups. Create separate group for readers and contributors (for each project), add them to SP and TFS. Then add and remove users from these groups.
2. Use [Team Foundation Server Administration Tool](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=tfsadmin) as centralized tool. This tools was created for TFS 2013. But TFS 2015 supports TFS 2013 object model. You have to (on your local workplace) install [Team Foundation Server 2013 object model](http://aka.ms/TFSOM2013), download archive, rename last release to TFS AdministrationTool.zip and install it.